# Ant task replace escaped URI param

Tags: regex, ant, html-entities

I'm trying to use Ant to remove a url parameter in an xml file.

The line in the xml is similar to below.

```
<from uri="http://www.google.com?q=test&amp;somethingElse=something" />
```

I want to remove the "&somethingElse=something". "something" could be different values so it must be generic.

I've tried

```
<replaceregexp file="somefile.xml" match="&amp;somethingElse(.*)" replace='" />' flags="gs" byline="true" />

<replaceregexp file="somefile.xml" match="\&amp;somethingElse(.*)" replace='" />'  byline="true" />

<replaceregexp file="somefile.xml" match="(&amp;)somethingElse(.*)" replace='" />'  flags="gs" byline="true" />
```

but those don't seem to work.

$(ant.regexp.regexpimpl) is not set so the default engine is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get `&` you need to write `&amp;` in the Ant build file because it is XML. To match `&amp;somethingElse` in the input of the `replaceregexp` Ant task you might therefore need to specify `&amp;amp;somethingElse` in the Ant build file.